# Display User data from Mysql using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I want to display data in my own format from Mysql database connecting through ASP.NET.
Currently I'm using MySQLDataGrid to display values in table format.

My code is

```
myConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; user id=root; password='';       database=test; pooling=false;")
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tablename;"
myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection)
myDataSet = New Dataset()
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "mytable")
MySQLDataGrid.DataSource = myDataSet
MySQLDataGrid.DataBind()
and asp code is:
<asp:DataGrid id="MySQLDataGrid" runat="server" />
```

its displaying all columns in Grid format.
But i actually wanted to display in HTML table format with some included/exclude fields. like below.

UserName : 
City :
Address:
etc...

Can I have a simple example code on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, columns are auto-generated corresponding to the binded datasource. You can disable this with the property AutoGenerateColumns by setting it to False:

```
<asp:DataGrid ... AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Then you can define yourself the columns you'd like to show under the `<columns/>` tag

```
<asp:DataGrid ... >    
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn 
            HeaderText="Username" 
            DataField="UserName"/>

        <asp:BoundColumn 
            HeaderText="City" 
            DataField="City"/>

        ...

    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

There a few types of columns:

> **BoundColumn** Displays a column bound to a field in a data source. It displays each item in the field as text. This is the default column type of the DataGrid control.
>
> **ButtonColumn** Displays a command button for each item in the column. This allows you to create a column of custom button controls, such as Add or Remove buttons.
>
> **EditCommandColumn** Displays a column that contains editing commands for each item in the column.
>
> **HyperLinkColumn** Displays the contents of each item in the column as a hyperlink. The contents of the column can be bound to a field in a data source or static text.
>
> **TemplateColumn** Displays each item in the column following a specified template. This allows you to provide custom controls in the column.

The [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) for the DataGrid show a bunch of example on how to use the different types of columns (button columns, add a checkbox...)